# Rails' upsert_all usage on insert AND update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to use the `upsert_all` method to update and insert all records (from ActiveRecord models) at the same time in my Postgres database. However, I come across a problem. 
I first fetch existing records and update them, that makes sense as the record ID (which is my primary key) is needed to update it using the `upsert_all` method.
For new records though, I don't have an ID, but have to set one as `upsert_all` requires to  have the same keys for all records, so I must set the ID, and I though setting it to `nil` might work. When doing this, I get the following error:
`PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

So how am I supposed to use the `upsert_all` method in Rails?
Is there a way to specify that if the ID is nil, the value is bypassed and auto-incremented by postgres?

Comment: Can you post your code implementing this? Do you have unique constraints?

Comment: +1 to the above person's comment, but also have you reviewed the documentation for this? It demonstrates how to use it and links to the source code. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert_all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example from the rails documentation should tell you everything you need to know:

```
# Inserts multiple records, performing an upsert when records have duplicate ISBNs.
# Here "Eloquent Ruby" overwrites "Rework" because its ISBN is duplicate.

Book.upsert_all([
  { title: "Rework", author: "David", isbn: "1" },
  { title: "Eloquent Ruby", author: "Russ", isbn: "1" }
], unique_by: :isbn)

Book.find_by(isbn: "1").title # => "Eloquent Ruby"
```

So ... no, you don't need to know the IDs for the records. How can you know the IDs for records you haven't created yet? But, you should guide the `upsert_all` method on how to identify which record to update by passing `unique_by`.

Another example of this might be updating a bunch of users. Yes they'll all have a ID in the database, but they should also all have a unique email or username or something:

```
User.upsert_all([
  { email: "bob@acme.com", role: "manager" },
  { email: "new-user@example.com", role: "customer" }
], unique_by: :email)
```

In this example, `bob@acme.com` already existed, but `new-user@example.com` did not. Bob had his role updated, and new-user had their account created.

Comment: I ended up creating a unique index that I gave to `upsert_all` in the `unique_by` arg. Works great, thanks